# How to solve issue when text input loses focus after typing one character in Angular

Tags: css, angular

I'm facing the following problem: after typing one character field loses focus. Could you tell me how to solve this issue?

```
<div *ngIf="ngControl.control.getError('required')">
            <div class='input-container border'>
                <input
                [class.is-invalid]="ngControl.touched && ngControl.invalid"
                type="{{ type }}"
                class="form-control input-height w-100"
                [formControl]="ngControl.control"
                required
                />
                <label for="{{label}}">{{label}}</label>
    </div>
```

styles for input

```
input[required] + label {
    color: $color-gray-300;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding-left: rem(21);
    bottom: 50%;
    transform: translateY(50%);
}

input[required] + label:after {
    content:'*';
    color: red;
}


input[required]:invalid + label {
    display: inline-block;
}


input[required]:valid + label{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This could be happening because the `ngIf` on the enclosing `div`. Try removing that and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely somethings triggers rerendering of the input. So that focused input is removed from DOM and a new input instanciated and added to the DOM.
It could be due to the `*ngIf="ngControl.control.getError('required')"` or to the other code above the input. For example, `*ngFor` loop which assigns the `ngControl` variable if there is such a loop.

Comment: This ngIf is causing the problem but how to solve it?

Comment: `display: none` instead of `*ngIf` usually is an option. It is difficult to understand why is `*ngIf` where at first place. maybe reviewing it's logic first would be a better approach